# Bijection between topology and topological space

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I've been working with a class of topological spaces $(X,\tau)$ with the following property:

There exists a bijection $f:X\to \tau\setminus\varnothing$ such that for all $x\in X$, $x\in f(x)$ (And, $|X|>1$ to avoid discrete topological spaces).

Is there a name for such a topological space? Are the reals under the standard topology an example of this topology?

Comment: Why such spaces? They have no name that **I**'ve ever come across (FWIW)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any space where $|X| = |\tau| = |U|$ for every non-empty open $U$ *and* (ETA) $|\{U \in \tau: x \in U \}| = |X|$ for every $x \in X$ will have such a bijection, by a simple transfinite construction (assuming AC). That includes the reals.

Index $X = \{x_\alpha: \alpha < \kappa\}$ and $\tau \setminus \emptyset = \{U_\alpha : \alpha < \kappa\}$ by $\kappa = |X|$. Construct $f$ recursively by letting $f(x_\lambda)$ be $U_\alpha$ for the least $\alpha$ such that $x_\lambda \in U_\alpha$ but $U_\alpha \neq f(x_\beta)$ for any $\beta < \lambda$. This is always possible as $|\lambda| < \kappa$ so there must be open sets containing $x_\lambda$ that haven't been used
yet. $f$ is obviously injective and has each $x \in f(x)$ so it only remains to show it is surjective. If some $U_\mu$ is not in the image of $f$, then at every stage of the construction when $x_\lambda \in U_\mu$, $U_\mu$ was not chosen and so $f(x_\lambda) = U_\alpha$ for some $\alpha < \mu$ but that is not
possible by cardinality (there are $\kappa$ points in $U_\mu$)

Comment: Could you briefly outline the construction? My set theory is rusty.

Comment: I've added the construction, and also noticed that it requires the extra condition that every point is in $|X|$ distinct open sets, which the reals do satisfy.

Comment: You use the total resolvability of $\Bbb R$, essentially. The argument is very similar, almost identical.